# Showing anatta from modern psychology or neuroscience?

Tags: anatman, science

I have heard Ajahn Brahm say in a talk, if I recall, that modern science or psychology has demonstrated anatta in some way.

It seems unnecessary to invoke science to validate any of Buddhism, but until one can see no self from direct experience, looking at science may be beneficial for the purpose of gaining an intellectual understanding.

Is there any useful research or writing is there that shows anatta from the perspective of modern psychology or neuroscience?

I'd think something like this would be produced by the Mind & Life Institute. All I could find is [this blurb](http://bigthink.com/ideafeed/good-news-science-buddha-agree-theres-no-you) crediting Evan Thompson. It doesn't say much.

Comment: `It doesn't say much` The bigthing article you referenced seems to be based on a qz article whose main scientific reference (i.e. reference to a scientific paper) is to [Reconstructing and deconstructing the self: cognitive mechanisms in meditation practice](https://www.cell.com/trends/cognitive-sciences/fulltext/S1364-6613(15)00152-7).

Comment: IMO this is off-topic and too broad: if the question were e.g., "Does *Christianity* teach anatta in some way?" that that would be pretty clearly off-topic, wouldn't it? IMO it's still off-topic if you substitute "modern science" or "psychology" or "neurology" or "philosophy". Also it's not clear what anatta means (I mean, maybe it's clear in the canon, but there have been more than 100 questions about it on his site). So asking, "is there anything in modern science comparable to the doctrine of anatta?" isn't good.

Comment: I think this is a good question because a good answer would use what is essentially  experiments [science] for demonstrable basis in explaining one's subjective understanding of anatta. I don't think experimental data is comparable to christianity.

Comment: Latter is essentially a theory which may be falsified by experimental data. If one wants to learn anything here then one should subject theories to scrutiny based on experimental data & philosophical integrity. A policy which restricts this is actually just punishing those who are capable of doing it.

Comment: I do think that it's very niche and perhaps one should make the distinction between scientific theory and scientific data very clear. Then one could allow comparative questions if restricted to the factual experimental data and established truths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not difficult for modern western scientific materialist/reductionists to understand the most coarse and obvious meaning of anatta: the lack of a permanent, unitary, and independent person.

In this culture, we are trained to look at the world from the default viewpoint of scientific materialist/reductionism. That people can be viewed as a composite of sub-atomic particles governed by the laws of chemistry and physics. We learn in elementary and middle school about caloric intake, cellular division (mitosis and meiosis), evolution, genetics and epigenetics which all *make it trivial* to ascertain that the person is *thoroughly non-permanent, non-unitary, and dependent.*

So if modern culture makes it so easy to arrive at the coarse meaning of anatta, then why aren't we all Arhats??

Because there is much more to realizing emptiness than just this very coarse and trivial understanding of anatta. For the wisdom realizing emptiness to have its soteriological effect the following must be true:

1. It can not be trivial. If it were trivial, then it would not have any power whatsoever to cure our suffering or pull us out of this endless cyclic existence.
2. It can not be mere word games or simply an intellectual philosophical exercise. If it were, then again it would not have any ability to end our suffering.
3. It can not mean that nothing exists. If we come to the conclusion that nothing exists, then there can be no clearer guidepost saying “turn around!” as it is stated over and over in the Dharma that this is manifest evidence that the reasoning on emptiness has gone astray.
4. Still, it must be something that can be inferred from reasoning. It is not a completely obscure phenomena.

Even a mere correct inferential understanding of emptiness or the object of negation should *rock* something deep inside of you. If it doesn't *absolutely shake* your deeply ingrained ignorance, then how could it ever have the power to uproot suffering?

Similarly, if you become convinced that some understanding of emptiness is leading you to believe that the world does not exist, or that karma does not exist, or rebirth does not exist, then you can be absolutely sure that there is some mistake in your understanding. The Virtuous Teachers warn again and again that the true meaning of emptiness does not equate to nihilism or the repudiation of the Four Noble Truths in any shape or form. In other words, keep looking.

So, looking to modern science - including psychology or neuroscience - to help arrive at coarse level of anatta is fine.

To arrive at the subtler levels will require more powerful tools. In terms of modern science, Relational QM is perhaps one of those tools. [See an article by Carlo Rovelli here.](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=it&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fettoremarini.com%2F2017%2F12%2F10%2Flezioni-di-fisica-buddhista-le-cose-sono-solo-relazioni-di-carlo-rovelli%2F)

But looking towards modern scientific materialists/reductionists to provide even a glimpse of the subtlest meaning of anatta or emptiness is unfortunately futile. Which is evident by looking around to see how many modern scientists appear to be highly realized beings teaching the Dharma...

Comment: "So if modern culture makes it so easy to arrive at the coarse meaning of anatta..." then why do we not all see no self or understand emptiness?

Comment: Because even with a course understanding of emptiness, one can still say that a self arises as an emergent thing, from what you listed:  caloric intake, cellular division, evolution, genetics and epigenetics, composite of sub-atomic particles governed by the laws of chemistry and physics. How do we deny that such a thing exists? (This is still a question to me.) To say it exists only conventionally or relatively, does not mean it does not exist. How do we see that there is no self at all, not even a conditioned, impermanent one?

Comment: We don’t deny that persons exist on the conventional level! The Buddha did not deny this nor did Nagarjuna or any of the Virtuous Teachers. You and I exist! That should not be disputed. The question is how do we exist? Under ultimate analysis no person can be found. Not even the slightest bit. We are utterly void of inherent existence.

Comment: `The Buddha did not deny this` Did the Buddha affirm it? Which bit[s] of the canon are you thinking of when you said that? It's famously affirmed by [Nagasena (in the parable of the chariot)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vajira_(Buddhist_nun)#Later_Usage).

Comment: @avatarKorra `one can still say that a self arises` Yes there is a view (are probably several views) about self. And there are views of non-self (including materialist [wrong] views of "nothing but atoms") etc. So, there *are* many different views, different kinds of view, in the world. Only, IMO, Buddhism says that any of the various views-of-self result in confusion and suffering: so it's better to not hold to those views.

Comment: @avatarKorra  `How do we deny that such a thing exists?` IMO there are several ways to deny (possible reasons to reject) a given "view" or "scientific theory"; for example: 1) the theory doesn't fit the observed facts (i.e. the observations); 2) the theory doesn't make accurate predictions about the future (future observations); 3) or, its predictions may be accurate but they're not useful, beneficial; 4) some theoreticians also say we should reject a theory that isn't "falsifiable". IMO the self-view can be "attacked" on any or all of these  grounds (i.e. using any of these reasons/methods).

Comment: @avatarKorra Also, beware, I think that "I don't exist" is *also* described in the canon to be a type of "self-view", i.e. "a view about self", i.e. one of the many types of self-views that leads to confusion and dukkha.

Comment: @ChrisW In the Trisaṁvaranirdeśa it says, "Ordinary people argue with me, but I do not argue with them be cause whatever is asserted to be in the world I also say exists. Whatever is asserted to be nonexistent in the world I also say is nonexistent." I think this comes from the Mahayana though.

Comment: @Tenzin Dorje perhaps you can trace this Trisaṁvaranirdeśa to Sutra in English? I found it in Ocean of Reasoning...

Comment: @ChrisW I also found this where the Buddha is not disputing - even affirming! - the conventional notion of self: https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.022.than.html, ""And which is the carrier of the burden? 'The person,' it should be said. This venerable one with such a name, such a clan-name. This is called the carrier of the burden."

Comment: Thank you, sorry, my mistake -- you were talking about "person"; I thought we were talking about "self".

Comment: In terms of conventional usage I'm not sure the distinction in this case.

Comment: Dictionary definitions: [atta](https://suttacentral.net/define/atta) versus [puggala](https://suttacentral.net/define/puggala). And there's a [footnote](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.022.than.html#fn-1) in the sutta you referenced, It's just that suttas speak against views of self ("nothing deserves to be called 'self'" and "self-views arise from attending inappropriately, are a thicket of views, and lead to suffering"). IMO and the footnote says that the "conventional versus ultimate" distinction/debate comes from scholastics after the Buddha's passing; not suttas.

Comment: Ok, thanks @ChrisW for the definitions! With those definitions I can say unequivocally that it is puggala that we say exists conventionally, not atta or a soul. In no way is atta or soul said to exist either conventionally or ultimately by Prasangikas.

Comment: @ChrisW `And there are views of non-self (including materialist [wrong] views of "nothing but atoms") etc.` Buddhism asserts that the body is constituted by way of [material elements](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nyanasatta/wheel019.html), and that a person is made up of the five aggregates. In what way does the materialist view differ from Buddhism on the discussion of self?

Comment: @avatar Korra, perhaps that would be best posed as a new question instead of comment?

Comment: @avatarKorra -- the (material) body is just one of five aggregates, and none of the aggregates are worth regarding as "self". || Yeshe -- I think the [definition of atta](https://suttacentral.net/define/atta) gives *three* meanings ... and that the first (i.e. soul) is non-existent (i.e. it's asserted that there is no such thing) ... the second (i.e. self-view, maybe selfishness) is unwise (a view which arises from attending inappropriately and which leads to suffering) ... and the third use (as a reflexive pronoun) does appear, during dialog, unremarkably or without comment.

Comment: @YesheTenley it is now [posted](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/26359/difference-between-buddhist-and-materialist-views-on-self) as a new question.

Comment: @YesheTenley: Returning to the question, `So if modern culture makes it so easy to arrive at the coarse meaning of anatta, then why aren't we all Arhats??` It seems to me that modern scientific reductionists/materialists maintain the ignorance that there is still something called "I" or "mine". Would you agree/disagree? Calling anything "I" or "mine" immediately shows a misunderstanding of no self, since, would one who truly understands anatta do this? This ignorance of "mine", misunderstanding anatta, is why so many hear the words of the coarse meaning of anatta yet are not arhats, it seems.

Comment: @avatar Korra, Using the words "I" and "mine" is not necessarily indicative that the person using the words has a misunderstanding of reality or a misunderstanding of no self. These words can be used conventionally and Prasangika does not think there is anything wrong with using these words conventionally. OTOH, I entirely agree that modern scientific reductionists/materialists maintain views based upon ignorance. Tsongkhapa's Great Treatise Volume 3 page 214 talks about "I" and "mine" and what the *view* (as opposed to the mere words) of these entails. Hope this helps.

Comment: I should clarify. A materialist/reductionist "calls", but to be more precise, "grasps at", their body, mind, or something material, as "mine", do they not? Is the purpose of sattipathana not to see that there is no self, i.e. that there are body, feelings, mind, and dhammas, and that these are not me, nor mine, nor a self? And then is the purpose of seeing anatta not to see that nothing is worth adhering to (MN 37,3)? This is the meaning of "I" or "mine" that was meant in the last comment. But using "I" or "mine" in conventional language, without grasping, agreed, is not neccesarily ignorance.

Comment: @avatarKorra Yes, I think this is correct although to be fair to materialist/reductionists we all (sentient beings) make this mistake ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Please see Quartz article dated February 9, 2018 by Ephrat Livni, entitled "[Scientists studying psychoactive drugs accidentally proved the self is an illusion](https://qz.com/1196408/scientists-studying-psilocybin-accidentally-proved-the-self-is-an-illusion/)". Research papers are linked in it.

Also, please see the TED Talk by neuroscientist [Anil Seth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anil_Seth) entitled "[Your brain hallucinates your conscious reality](https://youtu.be/lyu7v7nWzfo)" which was published on YouTube on July 18, 2017.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check out Consciousness Explained, a 1991 book by Daniel Dennett.

> Dennett puts forward a "multiple drafts" model of consciousness, suggesting that there is no single central place (a "Cartesian Theater") where conscious experience occurs; instead there are "various events of content-fixation occurring in various places at various times in the brain". The brain consists of a "bundle of semi-independent agencies"; when "content-fixation" takes place in one of these, its effects may propagate so that it leads to the utterance of one of the sentences that make up the story in which the central character is one's "self".

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it.

Behaviorism which ignores the underlying philosophical framework of behavior altogether whilst focusing on reward circuitry & conditioning of pattern recognition, shows that to an extent behavior is dictated by classical conditioning.

This is how one would train a dog with reward/punishment and more or less ignoring what he thinks.

Neuroscience developed in course of the development of psychopharmacological research and was predicated on hardcore behaviorism & molecular biology.

Eventually it became evident that the subjective philosophy of a person impacts his values & behavior as well but there was little to no study of this.

At this point consciousness research and cognitive behavioral therapy were in the infancy and pople wanted to study the psychological effects of character-changing experiences such as spiritual, mystical or great learning.

The natural course is that this would be still an extention of pharmacology and therefore the academic consciousness study turned to researching psychedelic drugs.

I think it can be summed up that behavioral science holds a person's understanding of the context of his experiences shapes his motivations and circumstances shape the behavior circuitry accordingly.

Afaik as to Anatta in particular, scientific litterature makes a strong case for there being no free-will, rather there being conditioning only and that neurobroadcasting is a reliable predictor of behavior and that maybe more so than a person's own philosophy which is generally more or less speculative & with cognitive dissonance.

Another interesting point is that there is some litterature on what exact brain activity is associated with the notion of self and the way this plays out has been surprising to people as it's not what a naive person would expect.

Eg when people think about death, what lights up are regions that are associated with other beings rather than that which has to do with oneself.

Here a person would say that **he/she** or that "self" thinks that death is something that applies to all beings but the circuitry tells a different story and the circuitry is the actual behavioral wiring.

If there indeed was an element of self then one would expect a different circuitry.

The field of 'general semantics' is probably closest to understanding anatta.

General semantics is concerned with how electrocolloidal events are abstracted as objects of perceptions, how these are further classified by words for thought, how these words are likewise more or less of an abstraction and how we might gain a measure of control over our own behavior & mental wellness through insight.

Imo one could say that general semantics establishes the emptiness of words and explains how delusion about these truths is a mental illness.